# Samba4 User password is not updated correctly via LDAP message, only via smbpasswd

Tags: ldap, samba, .net

I have set up a Samba4 AD DC, and I can successfully authenticate with my `Administrator` user from .net code:

```
var directoryIdentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("127.0.0.1", 636);
var credentials = new NetworkCredential($"CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ldap,DC=test,DC=dev", "admin1234!");
using(var connection = new LdapConnection(directoryIdentifier, credentials)) 
{
    try 
    {
        connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
        connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
        connection.SessionOptions.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOptions.None;

        connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

        connection.Bind(credentials);
    }
}
```

Then with this connection, I create a new user:

```
        var addRequest = new AddRequest(
            "CN=testuser,CN=Users,DC=ldap,DC=test,DC=dev",
            new DirectoryAttribute("objectClass", new object[] { "user" }),
            new DirectoryAttribute("cn", "testuser"),
            new DirectoryAttribute("uid", "testuser"),
            new DirectoryAttribute("sAMAccountName", "testuser"),
            new DirectoryAttribute("unicodePwd", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes($@"""pw1234!"""))
        );
        var addResponse = connection.SendRequest(addRequest);

        Console.WriteLine($"[ADD] response: {addResponse.ErrorMessage}");
```

or doing the same from terminal:

```bash
ldapadd -H LDAPS://127.0.0.1:636 -D "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ldap,DC=test,DC=dev" -w admin1234!
dn: CN=testuser,CN=Users,DC=ldap,DC=test,DC=dev
objectClass: user
cn: testuser
uid: testuser
unicodePwd:: IgBwAHcAMQAyADMANAAhACIA
sAMAccountName: testUser
```

where I got the unicodePwd from `echo -n "\"pw1234\!\"" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE | base64`.

However, when trying to authenticate with this user:

```
var testUser_directoryIdentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("127.0.0.1", 636);
var testUser_credentials = new NetworkCredential($"CN=testuser,CN=Users,DC=ldap,DC=test,DC=dev", "pw1234!");
using(var connection = new LdapConnection(testUser_directoryIdentifier, testUser_credentials)) 
{
    try 
    {
        connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
        connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
        connection.SessionOptions.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOptions.None;

        connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

        connection.Bind(testUser_credentials);
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> The supplied credential is invalid. [ErrorCode 49]

Similarly, for the terminal command

```bash
ldapwhoami -vvv -H ldaps://127.0.0.1:636 -D "CN=testuser,CN=Users,DC=ldap,DC=test,DC=dev" -x -w pw1234\!
```

I get

> ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
> additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 533, v1db1

When executing `ldbsearch -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb '(cn=testuser)' unicodePwd` on the samba AD DC, I get back this:

```
# record 1
dn: CN=testuser,CN=Users,DC=ldap,DC=test,DC=dev
unicodePwd:: 0pQq91kmGPJQOuQ3oiHPgg==

[...]
```

(Side question, `0pQq91kmGPJQOuQ3oiHPgg==` does not equal what I passed in, `IgBwAHcAMQAyADMANAAhACIA`, no idea why. Seems unrelated though.)

However, when I use the `smbpasswd` tool and setting the same password, it seems to work:

```bash
smbpasswd testuser
```

I can confirm this by again executing `ldbsearch -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb '(cn=testuser)' unicodePwd` and receiving the same record back.

This time, the same bash script works:

```bash
ldapwhoami -vvv -H ldaps://127.0.0.1:636 -D "CN=testuser,CN=Users,DC=ldap,DC=test,DC=dev" -x -w pw1234\!
ldap_initialize( ldaps://127.0.0.1:636/??base )
u:DEV-AD\testUser
Result: Success (0)
```

Why doesn't a simple LDAP message work (that is completely according the `unicodePwd` specification of Active Directory)? Does smbpasswd update something else too that is used when authenticating via `ldapsearch -D -w` or .net's `LdapConnection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify account options via `userAccountControl`. It's a bitmask ([documented at MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties)) that should have, at minimum, 512 for the NORMAL_ACCOUNT flag. If you don't specify, it defaults to `546` which means `ACCOUNT_DISABLED | PASSWD_NOTREQD | NORMAL_ACCOUNT`.

> (Side question, `0pQq91kmGPJQOuQ3oiHPgg==` does not equal what I passed in, `IgBwAHcAMQAyADMANAAhACIA`, no idea why. Seems unrelated though.)

AD never stores plaintext passwords; unicodePwd is a magic attribute that has server-side processing to turn the password into an NT hash (plus Kerberos AES keys which are stored in another attribute).

Comment: This works. I am pretty new to this whole Samba, AD, LDAP world, I had no idea this was the default behavior. (I checked with `ldbsearch -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb '(cn=testuser)' userAccountControl` and you are right, it returned `546`.) Thank you so much!

Comment: However, weirdly, both the previous and the new password are accepted. No idea why that is, but that's another question.

Comment: Got it, for 60 minutes, AD allows the old password to be used. :)

Comment: That sounds like it's meant to allow for replication, as most AD environments have more than one domain controller.